# ASP.net Razor Page code first: how do i add tables to the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, migration, razor-pages

I succesfully created the database with all the identity tables but when trying to add an additional table it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong?

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext: IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options): base(options)
    {

    }
    DbSet<ProjectModel> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectModel>().ToTable("Projects");
  
    }
}
```

Migration is succesfully created but even after writing `update-database` the table's in sql-server don't change
Inside the migration i see this:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity("BugTracker.Models.ProjectModel", b =>
            {
                b.Property<int>("Id")
                    .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                SqlServerPropertyBuilderExtensions.UseIdentityColumn(b.Property<int>("Id"), 1L, 1);

                b.Property<bool>("Active")
                    .HasColumnType("bit");

                b.Property<DateTime>("Created")
                    .HasColumnType("datetime2");

                b.Property<string>("Description")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.Property<int>("ProjectCreatorId")
                    .HasColumnType("int");

                b.Property<string>("ProjectName")
                    .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

                b.HasKey("Id");

                b.ToTable("Projects");
            }
```

yet the Sql looks like this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/lml3V.png
What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently after i moved the project class in the same folder with ApplicationDbContext it worked. Is this something that it's always necesarry?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This seems to be something that would be more appropriate as an edit of your question, instead of an answer to your question